# French canadian in SharePoint 2010 control with Regional Settings?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, localization, culture, regional-settings

is it possible to override the way a `Literal` or `Localize` control determines, which language should be used for localization?

We are currently in need to support fr-FR and fr-CA in two different SharePoint variations, originating from the same base. Sadly, there is no fr-CA language pack available for MOSS2010 and so we are not able to set this language in the variation settings. We are playing with the idea of getting the right culture from the regional settings (`CurrentCulture`), but at the moment I have neither a clue whether this would be feasible nor how to achieve this.

Keep in mind: We need this handling to be limited to the controls in our respective web part, so setting the culture of the current page would not be a solution.

Regards and thanks in advance,
Boris